# An embedding question: Morrey spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

> **Question.** If $u\in L^1$ and $Du$ is in the dual of the Holder space $C^\alpha$, then is it possible to say $u$ belongs to some Morrey space $L^{1, \delta}$?